# MongoDB percentage of strings in a collection

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to know if there's a way in MongoDB where it can display the percentage of fields on a collection containing a specific String.

So far what I have tried is getting the number of documents that match the string and the total number of documents, I could get the percent by manually doing the math, although I imagine MongoDB should have either a query or an aggregation to do this, but I can't find how.

this are the queries I used

```
db.enron.find({ $text: { $search: "\"Kenneth Lay\""}}).count()
398
> db.enron.count()
5929
```

and this is the db squema

https://i.stack.imgur.com/asTXn.png

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811084/efficiently-count-percentage-of-occurrence-in-mongodb